# Why does Javascript function work in XQuery even though it is declared prior to including the file

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Can someone explain why the Javascript test function works even though the XQuery function is declared prior to including the script in the HTML?

**test.js**

```
function test(){
  alert('from test');
}
```

**index.xqy**

```
declare function local:test(){
  for (: do something :)
  return (
    <script>
    test("Testing...")
    </script>
  )
};

xdmp:set-response-content-type("text/html; charset=utf-8"),
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">',
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
{
  local:test()
}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the XQuery code in `index.xqy` is executed server-side, so `local:test()` is called and evaluated before it gets to the browser. The first thing the browser sees is the Doctype declaration, and it evaluates the page with the result of `local:test()` already rendered.

Comment: Static error? It is just a node constructor not a string

Comment: @BeniBela Yeah, I misread that. I removed that note from the answer. Thanks.